# Getting Exception java.util.NoSuchElementException: key not found: 'text' in spark-cassandra-connector

Tags: java, cassandra, spark-streaming, twitter-streaming-api, spark-cassandra-connector

I want to save data from spark RDDs to cassandra table. I am using spark-cassandra-connector for java from 
https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector

Code to save as per docs

```
rddJavaFunctions.writerBuilder("populartweets", "stream_tag_count",
                CassandraJavaUtil.mapToRow(Tag.class)).withColumnSelector(CassandraJavaUtil.someColumns("tag","count"))
                .saveToCassandra();
```

After this operation I am getting error

```
    New Cassandra host /127.0.0.1:9042 added
15/12/16 10:18:06 INFO CassandraConnector: Connected to Cassandra cluster: Test Cluster
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException: key not found: 'text'
    at scala.collection.MapLike$class.default(MapLike.scala:228)
    at scala.collection.AbstractMap.default(Map.scala:58)
    at scala.collection.MapLike$class.apply(MapLike.scala:141)
    at scala.collection.AbstractMap.apply(Map.scala:58)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.types.ColumnType$.fromDriverType(ColumnType.scala:81)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.ColumnDef$.apply(Schema.scala:117)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.Schema$$anonfun$com$datastax$spark$connector$cql$Schema$$fetchPartitionKey$1.apply(Schema.scala:199)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.Schema$$anonfun$com$datastax$spark$connector$cql$Schema$$fetchPartitionKey$1.apply(Schema.scala:198)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:244)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:244)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:727)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1157)
    at scala.collection.IterableLike$class.foreach(IterableLike.scala:72)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterable.foreach(Iterable.scala:54)
```

I am using spark 1.5.2

Comment: Hi, did you resolve this? I have similar error with cassandra 3.0 and spark-connector 1.5.0-M3

Comment: Not resolved yet... using basic insert statements for cassandra instead

Comment: Resolved this by downgrading to C* 2.2.4 :)

Answer (score -1):

This issue has been solved for Cassandra 3.x. Use spark-connector 1.5.0-RC1 (latest as of today).